# UIImagePickercontroller cancel button not display in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting saved images from photo album while clicking button. After dispalying photo album i don't have cancel button in iPad for cancel the photo album. After choosing anyone saved images from photo album then it closing and adding picking image to UIImageView. But without choosing image from gallery i'm not able to close the photo album. In iphone it's working with cancel.

```
-(void)picker:(id)sender{

if ([self->popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
 [self->popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

 } else {
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
 UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
 {
 imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

 imagePicker.delegate = self;

 imagePicker.allowsEditing =NO;

 imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

  self->popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
 initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];

 self->popoverController.delegate = self;


 CGRect popoverRect = [self.view convertRect:[self.view frame]
 fromView:[self.view superview]];

 popoverRect.size.width = MIN(popoverRect.size.width, 100) ;
 popoverRect.origin.x  = popoverRect.origin.x+10;



 [self->popoverController
 presentPopoverFromRect:popoverRect
 inView:self.view
 permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
 animated:YES];

 }



 -(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
 //release picker


 //  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }else{

 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 if (popoverController != nil) {
 [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 popoverController=nil;
 }

 }

}



 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{


 if (popoverController != nil) {
 [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
 popoverController=nil;
 }


 [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting the imagePickerController in a popoverController, so it will not have Manual Cancel button because you can tap anywhere outside the popover to dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

I've met this problem before. Please check the accepted answer in my question below. It worked for me.

[UIImagePickerController inside UIPopoverController doesn't show Cancel button on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922471/uiimagepickercontroller-inside-uipopovercontroller-doesnt-show-cancel-button-on?noredirect=1#comment42393741_26922471)