# UIImagePickerController inside UIPopoverController doesn't show Cancel button on iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm using UIImagePickerController inside a UIPopoverController to select image just from photo albums. When I launch app on device running iOS 8, the Cancel button on the top right of the pop over appeared normally like this:

[image]

But when I launch the app on device running iOS 7, the Cancel button disappeared:
[image]

The code I used to show the picker:

```
    UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [pickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    pickerController.delegate = self;

    _popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerController];
    _popOver.delegate = self;

    pickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];//Cancel button text color
    [pickerController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}];// title color

    if (isImage) {
        [pickerController setMediaTypes:@[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage]];
    } else
        [pickerController setMediaTypes:@[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie]];
    [_popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(1024/2, 768/2, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

What can I do to show that Cancel button on iOS7? My app design doesn't allow user to dismiss the popover by tapping anywhere outside the popover view.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show me the relevant Code ?

Comment: Default the cancel button appears in iOS8

Comment: @SureshThoutam yes. But can I do something to show it on iOS7 too?

Comment: You don't need the Cancel button. The user simply taps outside the popover to dismiss it.

Comment: @rmaddy yes I know that. But my app design does not allow user to dismiss the popover by the usual way.

Comment: Please refer this answer if every case doesn't work stackoverflow.com/a/50490924/1201274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JozoL Write the Below Code this works

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

        UINavigationItem *pickerNavBarTopItem;
        // add done button to right side of nav bar
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                      target:self
                                                                      action:@selector(doSomething)];

        UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
        [bar setHidden:NO];
        pickerNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
        pickerNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
    }
    -(void)doSomething{

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It's worked. One more thing, when I choose an album, the Cancel button still disappeared, but on iOS8 it did not. Do you know why and could you explain more about this case?

Answer (score 1):

For swift2.x you can try below code, Its work for me

`pickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `UIImagePickerController` was not showing its cancel button
. So I tried adding this line to code:

```
pickerController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

And this worked for me.Try setting color of Cancel button like this

```
 pickerController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Try using this code and let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I used this but it didn't work. Suresh's solution worked for me.